# subquery in mysql case when clause

Tags: mysql, select

The following query works in oracle, but in mysql it produces an error:

```
SELECT id_propuestas, titulo, descripcion, id_usuario, votos,
case 
    when(select true 
        from votospropuestos
        where id_propuesta = propuestas.id_propuesta
        and id_usuario = 1) then true 
    else false 
end as votada 
FROM propuestas
```

Error message:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column `'propuestas.id_propuesta'` in `'where clause'`

Can anyone explain the problem and/or suggest a solution?

Comment: can you add a screen shot of your db setup?

Comment: easier than uploading a screenshot: can you post the structure of your tables? Use `show create table propuestas;` and `show create table votospropuestos;`

Comment: Just a guess: did you want to type `propuestas.id_propuestas` instead of `propuestas.id_propuesta`?

Comment: sorry , you have reason the name of the column is not correct, i am going to jump for the windows as a punishment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a subquery inside a `case`, but your query can easily be reworked to achieve your intention by using the `exists()` function:

```
SELECT id_propuestas, titulo, descripcion, id_usuario, votos,
exists(select *
     from votospropuestos 
     where id_propuesta = propuestas.id_propuesta
     and id_usuario = 1) as votada 
FROM propuestas
```

The `exists()` function returns `true` if any rows are returned from the subquery, `false` otherwise.

It would be far more efficient however to use a join:

```
SELECT p.id_propuestas, p.titulo, p.descripcion, p.id_usuario, p.votos,
    max(v.id_propuesta) IS NOT NULL as votada
FROM propuestas p
LEFT JOIN votospropuestos v
    ON v.id_propuesta = p.id_propuesta
    AND v.id_usuario = 1
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [SQL ANSI 1999](http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~cgutierr/cursos/BD/standards.pdf), which is the first appearance of the `CASE WHEN` statement in a standard, you can't use a subquery with it.