# Conditional SELECT SQL statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql

These 3 tables are set as follows in a MySQL database (not all columns are shown):
**events_table**

- id
- event_date
- event_type // Working day or holiday
- occasion // If event_type = 'holiday', occasion of holiday is entered here

**classes_table**

- id
- class_type
- teacher_id (foreign key. Reference = events_table.id)

**teachers_table**

- id
- name

I want to write a SQL query wherein I want to select data depending on the data in the `events_table.event_type` on a particular date i.e., if the `event_type` on the `event_date`(let's say 25th Dec) is holiday then `SELECT events_table.occasion...` else if `event_type` on the `event_date`(let's say 28th Aug) is working_day then `SELECT classes_table.id, classes_table.class_type`

```
IF events_table.event_type <> 'holiday' THEN

-- If event on a particular day was not a holiday, select the following

    SELECT
        classes_table.id,
        classes_table.class_type 
    FROM
        classes_table 
    WHERE
        teachers_table.username = 'teacher_name' 
        INNER JOIN teachers_table ON teachers_table.id = classes_table.teacher_id
ELSE

-- Else, select the following

   SELECT
        events_table.occasion 
    FROM
        events_table 
END IF
```

However as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26619281/13594557) answer it is not possible. Also we cannot use `IF...ELSE` without `BEGIN....END` blocks, however doing that too doesn't help me. Is there any way we can do this in MySQL (preferably without sub-queries), if not what would be the most efficacious way of implementing the same?

Comment: It is not that easy to interpret your pseudo-code. Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your question.