# Group by user and permission

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table and need to output the data in a way that permissions relevant to the area appear in the same row.

```
user   |  page    |  permission
-------------------------------
Jon    |  books   |   read
Jon    |  books   |   delete   
Jon    |  photos  |   read
Jon    |  photos  |   edit
```

Desired output in HTML (not a new table):

```
user   |   page   |  read  | edit  |  delete
-----------------------------------------------
Jon    |  books   |   X    |       |     X
Jon    |  photos  |   X    |   X   |
```

Basically I need to output the data and combine all rows that have the same user and page into a single row, where permissions become columns. I can write two queries but it seems to be inefficient to run second query from each row.

I tried grouping but it does not output all the results pertinent to each user:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
GROUP BY user, page
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can pivot the table with a lot of CASES and subqueries but in this problem I would use an store procedure with a temporal table that you fill with some selects. Can be that a possible workaround for you?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't need to alter my table -  I need to output the data and combine all rows that have the same user and page into a single row.

Comment: Most likely this is basic for someone writing queries frequently - I'm an occasional code poker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you missing some (fake) aggregation function .. try

```
select user, page
    , max(case when permission = 'read' then 'X' else '' end) read
    , max(case when permission = 'edit' then 'X' else '' end) edit
    , max(case when permission = 'delete' then 'X' else '' end) delete
from t1
group by user, page
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
e.user,
e.page
EXISTS (SELECT user FROM yourTable WHERE e.permission = 'read' AND e.user = user  AND e.page = page) as read,
EXISTS (SELECT user FROM yourTable WHERE e.permission = 'edit' AND e.user = user  AND e.page = page) as edit,
EXISTS (SELECT user FROM yourTable WHERE e.permission = 'delete' AND e.user = user AND e.page = page) as delete
FROM yourTable e
GROUP by e.user, e.page
```

From: [subquery in mysql case when clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618735/subquery-in-mysql-case-when-clause)